# Как пробросить файл из контейнера на хост?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Я пытаюсь пробросить файл базы данных sqlite из контейнера на хост по пути `/var/bot/data.db`, но он почему-то не пробрасывается. Что я делаю не так?

Вот структура моего проекта:

```
project
  |
  | bot
    | data.db
    | bot.py
  | requirements.txt
  | Dockerfile
  | docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /bot

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /bot .

CMD ["python", "bot.py"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenium_chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    container_name: selenium_chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    restart: always
  bot:
    build: .
    container_name: bot
    links:
      - selenium_chrome
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./bot/data.db:/var/bot/data.db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас неправильно подключается volume и приложение работает с не тем файлом, который вы ожидаете.

Вот эта строка:

```
  - ./bot/data.db:/var/bot/data.db
```

подключит файл `bot/data.db` из каталога проекта на хосте в файловую систему контейнера по пути `/var/bot/data.db`. Обратите внимание, что файл будет в директории `/var/bot` *внутри* контейнера.

Если приложение не обращается к базе по пути `/var/bot/data.db`, то оно не будет модифицировать файл из `/var/bot` (в контейнере) и соответсвенно файл в директории `bot` проекта.

Правильно будет указать отображение для volume в формате `<путь на хосте>:<путь в контейнере>`.

Путь на хосте может быть относительным от директории с `docker-compose.yml` или абсолютным.